# I have a problem loading the elements in a list to a .h5 file

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, hdf5

```
import pandas as pd
for j in csv:
   j=j[:-4]
   pd.read_excel("{}.xlsx".format(j)).to_hdf('onedata.h5', key='{}'.format(j), mode='w')
```

Where csv is a list contaning all the items I want to write into the .h5 file. Since there is a large amount of data Iam trying to use the above code.
The problem is that the keys in .h5 file aren't displaying the elements loaded into them from the list. Any help appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: I would start by testing `pd.read_excel().to_hdf()` for a single csv and h5 file.

Comment: Okay. I'll try and let you know.

Comment: It worked fine by doing  this: `pd.read_excel({}.xlsx".format('FuelConsumption')).to_hdf('onedata.h5',key='{}'.format('Fuelconsumption'))`@kcw78

Comment: I assume "worked fine" means you checked the keys/datasets in `onedata.h5` and they are correct. If so, that's a good start. Repeat for the next csv file. I expect 1 of these outcomes: 1) `onedata.h5` has both datasets/keys, 2)  `onedata.h5` only has the second dataset/key, 3)  `onedata.h5` only has the first dataset/key, 4) error opening `onedata.h5`to write. This should help you isolate the error in your code.

Comment: When I use the for loop for loading the data , FuelConsumption is loaded twice (keys showing twice) into `onedata.h5`. And the rest all data is displayed only once. Can tell me the cause?@kcw78

Comment: You read from `"{}.xlsx.format(j)"` and write to `key='{}'.format(j)`. Somehow you are executing this statement with `j=FuelConsumption` twice. First check that `FuelConsumption.xlsx` is only in your `csv` list once. If not, it's not clear (to me) how/why/where it happens. I'm running out of ideas. Maybe add a `print (j)' statement to verify the loop variable.

Comment: Okay . I found the cause for the problem. Thank you for your time.@kcw78